# Are images generated by filereader cached in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption, cryptography

Since one can read local files using filereader it is possible display it in the web browser, e.g. if it is an image.

My idea is to decrypt an encrypted image using AES file encryption and simply display the result in browser, instead of generate and download the decrypted file, which is up and running on my own server using [AES file encryption](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2013/11/javascript-file-encrypter/)

I made a minor change in the code in step 3, instead to go to step 4 (download the file) I just generate the image using `$('body').prepend($('<img />').attr('id','secretimage').attr('src', decrypted));` which will add an image as a new DOM object using the base64 string equivalent of the file.

If dealing with encryption, you'll guess it's all about security issues. This image may / shall / will contain confidential information, let it be a contract, bank account details or any other confidential or secret content.

And here's the Question itself: Is it safe enough, to remove this image from the DOM using jquerys `.remove()` function, or is it to be found anywhere in the browsers cache ? Or are there other ways to secure and programmatically remove the image ?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: I'm not sure I need a tank :P Seriously though: what's *safe enough*? Undoubtedly it could linger in RAM at the very least. If the object in memory is not protected against writing, overwriting the memory would be certainly be recommended, but even then it may have been copied by the memory management or saved in the GPU memory etc.. A bigger problem might be to get the AES key itself to the browser though; in general you should just use TLS.

Answer (score 0):

The browser shouldn't cache your image if it is in the Base64 format.

You can't make your web application 100% secure as you don't have control over the garbage collection and memory management of the browser the users uses.
So you can only try to assure that only authenticated users can access the resources and that there is a low timeout span after which the user has to authenticate again.

And of course use TLS to be safe that the data doesn't get compromised on the way to the user.

Comment: Thanks so far. You mean, the base64 format image shouldn't be cached ? But isn't the src-attribute acting as a resource identifier like every other `src="http://path/to/image"` does ?

Comment: As far as I know it will only be cached if the js / html / css file that contains the base64 string is cached.